# Continue to load xparse in new packages?

Tags: xparse, package-writing

I am writing a package and intend to use the command `NewDocumentCommand`, which is available for newer installations of LaTeX (since 2020).

Should I still load the `xparse` package with `\RequirePackage{xparse}`?  Then my package will work for all users.  Is there any downside to loading `xparse` if it is not needed?

Would it be better to use something like `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020/10/01]`?

Is there a way to say "if you have an old version of LaTex" then load `xparse`, otherwise don't?

Comment: Perhaps you can check if `NewDocumentCommand` is defined, and if not, load `xparse`, as in `\ifdefined\NewDocumentCommand\else \usepackage{xparse}\fi`

Comment: If you load the package, then you also get the deprecated argument types that are not preloaded with Latex, so it adds unsupported functionality. That should be the only difference

Answer (score 2):

A package that relies on `xparse` may specify the required version as follows. Typically like this inside an `l3doc` documentation (dates given may not be up-to-date).

```
%</internal> 
%<package> \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020/02/02]
%<package> \RequirePackage{xparse}[2020/03/06]
```